# Find all Values greater than X and replace them with 0

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys I got a problem I don't remember the command to select all values in a column which are greater than X for replacing them with 0... Would be nice if someone could help me

Comment: Please learn [what is UPDATE statement?](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) statement

```
UPDATE table_name
   SET column_name = 0
 WHERE column_name > X
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c314/1)** demo

Comment: I copied it into HeidiSQL and it wont work. UPDATE item_template SET itemset = 0 WHERE itemset > 902;

Comment: It **should** work just fine. Did you see a working sqlfidle example? What is the exact error message are you getting if any? Do you correctly spell table and column names? What is the actual schema of your table?

Comment: /* Affected rows: 0  Gefundene Zeilen: 0  Warnungen: 0  Dauer von 1 query: 0,359 sec. */

Comment: That just tells you that 1) that update is executed without errors 2) you don't have any rows with `itemset > 902`. Another possibility is that `itemset` might be not of a numeric datatype.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I should press F5 more often :D I think I'm going to sleep now :D

Comment: That's all right. Happens to the best of us :). I'm glad it has been  resolved. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
update myTable set myField = 0 where myField > x
```

Comment: I copied it into HeidiSQL and it wont work. UPDATE item_template SET itemset = 0 WHERE itemset > 902;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
update tableX set colY = 0 where colY > 23;
```

Of course `23` can be parameterized as X if you want.

Comment: I copied it into HeidiSQL and it wont work.

UPDATE item_template SET itemset = 0 WHERE itemset > 902;

Comment: It should work just fine. What is the exact error message are you getting if any?

Comment: /* Affected rows: 0  Gefundene Zeilen: 0  Warnungen: 0  Dauer von 1 query: 0,359 sec. */

Comment: well that is not an error message.  Maybe there are no rows to update.

Comment: But there are rows with values greater than 902 :D

Comment: show me, your select query and your update query.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I should press F5 more often :D I think I'm going to sleep now :D